# Can IID_PPV_ARGS be skipped in jsctypes? (Win7)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I'm working on this line of code here:

```
  var pps = new IID;
  var ppv = ctypes.voidptr_t(0);
  var hr = SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(hwnd, pps.address(), ppv.address());
```

The place I'm converting from actually does this:

```
 IPropertyStore *pps;
 HRESULT hr = SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(hwnd, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pps));
```

So I'm just passing ppv as 0. But I'm not sure why hr is coming back error.

Can we skip IID_PPV_ARGS in ctypes, because i think its just doing something like memset, where it sets it to 0. This is the macro code:

```
/*http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
* void IID_PPV_ARGS(
*   T **pType
* );
*/
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yvesdolc/archive/2006/12/27/iid-ppv-args-macro.aspx

It looks like its just converting whatever i pass to it to a voidptr_t.

My full code is here, it can be copy pasted and it errors on the line hr line above.
https://gist.github.com/yajd/862832b07a1d46caef8b#comment-1255934

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot skip the IID.

You'll need to create a [`GUID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa373931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure type, fill in the IID of IPropertyStore (which is `"886D8EEB-8CF2-4446-8D02-CDBA1DBDCF99"`) and then call `SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow` like,

```
let IID = new ctypes.StructType("IID", [
  {Data1: ctypes.uint32_t},
  {Data2: ctypes.uint16_t},
  {Data3: ctypes.uint16_t},
  {Data4: ctypes.uint8_t.array(8)}
]);

// 886D8EEB-8CF2-4446-8D02-CDBA1DBDCF99
let IID_IPropertyStore = new IID();
console.log(IID_IPropertyStore);
IID_IPropertyStore.Data1 = 0x886D8EEB;
IID_IPropertyStore.Data2 = 0x8CF2;
IID_IPropertyStore.Data3 = 0x4446;
"8D;02;CD;BA;1D;BD;CF;99".split(";").forEach(function(e, i) {
  IID_IPropertyStore.Data4[i] = parseInt(e, 16);
});

SHGetPropertyStore(hwnd, IID_IPropertyStore.address(), ppv.address());
```

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you for that man. Is that what `IID_PPV_ARGS` does? You gave me two solutions in one. I like your method of `GUID` population better. I was doing it this way: `var myGUID = new struct_GUID(); var HR_myGUID = CLSIDFromString('{9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3}', myGUID.address()); checkHRESULT(HR_myGUID);` your way avoids another js-ctypes call. And I had no idea I had to do that on the pps I thought it was only for `pkey`s thanks man! I tried really hard before posting here, did you see my gist? :)

Comment: Oh btw, when ppl have `pps`, they always do a `pps->Release()` on it aftewrards [MSDN :: Release()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I won't be able to do such thing on my `pps` right? But MSDN says it just returns a `new reference count` so it's no big deal to do it your way above no?

Comment: I made a tutorial for populating `GUID`s without needing use WinAPI methodd based on your solution. I was going to ask how to do it one day. Heres tutorial: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/832f77cc4b9153ee67d8 :)

Comment: Hey man i wrote the tutorial but before I was going to sleep i noticed an issue. In the `Data4`, my method makes it be `[-88, -48, -31, -44, 45, -31, -43, -13]` but your method makes it be `[168, 208, 225, 212, 45, 225, 213, 243]`. Can you please check out the gist and comment. We don't want to be teaching people wrong stuff haha

Comment: Look at the types of `Data4` ;)

Comment: I tried changing the of data4 to be the same as i had it, `ctypes.char.array(8)` but the the code for the split and iterate through `parseInt(myGUID_3_4_joined.substr(i*2,2), 16);` would throw ctypes errors :( so i had to change it to match you which was ` ctypes.uint8_t.array(8)` but i dont know why. Shouldnt parseInt(blah, 16) work fine with my `ctypes.char.array(8)`?

Comment: Btw I tested this today and it worked!!! My gosh I dont know how u figured this one out. Im stuck on finding the c++ source code for the Release and SetVal functions, can you please link me to where you figured the above out, Im thinking it will have the C++ setval function and i can take it from there. Thx man!

Comment: Hey man can you please explain in words what `IID_PPV_ARG` does, I see the solution but like how would I explain this to my friend in just words?

Comment: `IID_PPV_ARG(arg)` is a macro that expand to two things: [`uuidof(arg)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zaah6a61.aspx) and `&arg`: `IID_PPV_ARG(arg) -> __uuidof(arg), &arg`.

Comment: Thanks man from where did you find that out? I couldn't understand that from other places. Btw the `&arg` does that mean `arg` is passed as reference?

Comment: Google. `&arg` means it does not pass `arg` but the address of `arg` (so a pointer to `arg`).

Comment: Oh I use bing maybe thats why i couldnt fig it out :P jk just looking for scape goat